# Как отправить файл через HttpClient?

Tags: c#, https

Нигде не нашёл рабочего способа отправки файла ( архива ) на хост через https.

Подскажите рабочий годный способ.( Желательно с комментариями в коде )

Нашёл этот код:

```
async Task UploadFile(string url, byte[] bytes, string name, string filename = null)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    using (var content = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        content.Add(new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)), name, filename ?? "q");

        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
}
```

Но как им пользоваться не пойму, толком не описали ничего и метод как использовать не написали.
Какие нужно обязательные параметры отправлять?
Как можно синхронно и асинхронно отправить архив на хост?

P.S: .Net 4.5

С `WebClient` конечно намного проще, но хотелось бы и такой способ поюзать

Comment: Здесь более понятно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928544/203463

Comment: @vusaldev, Писать туда не могу, напишу здесь 2-ой аргумент PostAttachment можно передавать только в байтах? Если это обычный файл или архив, как тогда отправить? Ничего не расписано, поэтому интересуюсь.

Comment: Как мне отправить обычный архив файл на хост? Без доп параметров и прочего POST запросом синхронно.

Comment: А в обычный файл или архив, по-вашему, состоит не из байтов?

Comment: @Anonymous, я думаю, с такими знаниями вы не вывезете. Можно изменить PostAttachment, чтобы он принимал файл, ссылку на файл, что угодно. Но если вы не знаете, как это делать, то вряд ли этот вопрос будет решён. Могу лишь дать ссылки на ресурсы,может станет яснее: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.3.php